# How do I line profile the main() function in Python flask app?

Tags: python, flask, profiling

Now,I can line profile all the functions that are in `main()`,as you can see the commented section,but I could not line profile the `main()` function itself. Please help me how to line profiling on the `main()` function.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():

    js = request.json


    supp_inv_date = js['PartnerInvoiceDate']

    lp = LineProfiler()

    conn, query = dbconnection(supp_inv_date)

    # lp_wrapper = lp(dbconnection)
    # lp_wrapper(supp_inv_date)
    # lp.print_stats()

    dfr = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

    df2 = is_similar_invno(dfr,js)

    df3 = is_similar_invamt(dfr,js)

    df4 = is_similar_invdate(dfr,js)

    df5 = is_similar_recvdate(dfr,js)

    # lp_wrapper = lp(is_similar_invno)
    # lp_wrapper(dfr,js)
    # lp.print_stats()

    # lp_wrapper = lp(is_similar_invamt)
    # lp_wrapper(dfr, js)
    # lp.print_stats()
    #
    # lp_wrapper = lp(is_similar_invdate)
    # lp_wrapper(dfr, js)
    # lp.print_stats()
    #
    # lp_wrapper = lp(is_similar_recvdate)
    # lp_wrapper(dfr, js)
    # lp.print_stats()


    score_list=calculate(dfr,df2,df3,df4,df5)

    # lp_wrapper = lp(calculate)
    # lp_wrapper(dfr,df2,df3,df4,df5)
    # lp.print_stats()

    # print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    dfr = final(dfr,score_list)
    print(dfr)

    try:
        res = dfr.to_dict()
    except:
        res = dfr.to_dict()

    response = {'dupes': res}

    return json.dumps(response)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    app.run(host='localhost', port='6000', debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Now,I can line profile all the functions that are in main(),as you can see the commented section,but I could not line profile the main() function.Please help me how to line profile the main() function I,e def main().

Comment: have tried wrap the code of main into another function and profile it?